# Construct $f$ satisfying certain given conditions

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, functions, derivatives

> Given $\textbf x\in \mathbb R^n$ and $r>0$, construct a function $f:\mathbb R^n\to [0,1]$ of class $C^\infty$ such that
> $$f^{-1}(1)=\overline{B(\textbf{x},r/2)}\\f^{-1}(0)=\mathbb R^n\setminus B(\textbf{x},r)$$

Being helpless about the original question (apart from the geometrical realization that it looks like a peninsula), I was trying the $n=1$ variant out. This translates to

> Given $a<b$, find a function $g:\mathbb R\to [0,1]$ of class $C^\infty$ such that
> $$g|_{(-\infty,a]}\equiv1\\g|_{[b,\infty)}\equiv0$$

Even this one seems quite out of my reach. The first idea I had was to use the Sigmoid function. But, that never gives a zero derivative except at $x\to \pm \infty$.

So, my next idea was to use the $C^\infty$ property of the function $y=e^{-\frac 1x}$ and construct $g$ locally at $x=a$ using the function
$$\alpha(x)=1-e^{-\frac 1{x-a}}$$
and locally at $x=b$ using the function
$$\beta(x)=e^{\frac 1{x-b}}$$
But, I couldn't proceed with this as well.

Comment: You might be interested in Urysohn's lemma, noting that the two sets $f^{-1}(1),f^{-1}(0)$ are disjoint and closed and $\Bbb R^n$ under the Euclidean topology satisfies Urysohn's conditions. Whether or not this function would be smooth I am not sure; Urysohn's lemma just gives continuity - you might have to tweak it a bit

Comment: @FShrike thanks for the suggestion- I didn't know of this lemma. But, I still don't seem to have any idea about the actual question :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following function

$ 
h(t)=
\begin{cases}
e^{-\frac{1}{t}} ~~~ \text{if}~~~t>0\\
0 ~~~~~~ \text{if}~~t\leq 0
\end{cases}
$

It is evident that h is smooth $\forall ~ x \neq 0$. To show that it is also smooth at $x=0$ one needs to show that the right-hand derivative vanishes (because the left-hand derivative vanishes) for all orders. This follows from the fact that the given exponential function vanishes quickly than any polynomial in $x$ - a fact that can be checked using basic exponential inequalities.

Now define the function
$
g(t)= \frac{h(b-t)}{h(b-t)+h(t-a)}.
$
For $t\geq b$, $h(b-t)=0$ and for $t\leq a$, $h(t-a)=0$. This implies
$
g(t) = 
\begin{cases}
1 ~~~\text{if } t\leq a\\
0 ~~~\text{if } t\geq b
\end{cases}
$

Notice that the denominator of $g$, namely $h(b-t)+h(t-a)$ - never vanishes. This implies that $g$ is smooth by quotient rule.
One should also check that $g$ is not unity on $(a,b)$.

Now consider the case $n=1$. We first construct a function $f_1:\mathbb{R} \to [0,1]$ such that $f_1^{-1}(1)= \overline{B(x,\frac{r}{2})}$ and
$f^{-1}(0)=\mathbb{R} \backslash B(\mathbf{x}, r)$. By the above construction one can easily construct smooth $ \tilde{g}_1,\tilde{g}_2:\mathbb{R}\to [0,1] $ such that
$
\tilde{g}_1(t) = 
\begin{cases}
1 ~~~\text{if } t\leq x+r/2\\
0 ~~~\text{if } t\geq x+r
\end{cases}
$

$
\tilde{g}_2(t) = 
\begin{cases}
1 ~~~\text{if } t\leq x-r\\
0 ~~~\text{if } t\geq x-r/2
\end{cases}
$

If we define $f_1 = \tilde{g}_1 \cdot \tilde{g}_2$, then one has $f_1^{-1}(1)= \overline{B(x,\frac{r}{2})}$ and
$f_1^{-1}(0)=\mathbb{R} \backslash B(\mathbf{x}, r)$.

Now try to construct a $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Sir, I can't construct $f$ on $\mathbb R^n$. Can you please help? Thanks by the way for the $g$ on $\mathbb R$ (+1).

Comment: Try considering the norm ||x|| on $\mathbb{R}^n.$

Comment: Got it sir. Thank you!